# How to match up soldering iron tip points with the right pad size?

Tags: soldering, soldering-iron-station

Sometimes it's really difficult to understand the heat transfer mechanism on the PCB from the soldering tip because I can see that the solder melts but it does not stick to the soldering pad and it keeps floating and so difficult to solder. Please suggest what can be done to solve this issue and how to adjust the temperature properly.

Comment: what exactly are you doing to melt the solder?

Comment: We would need more information to answer properly. There are many things that could be causing this: low heat, no flux, bad flux, bad PCB layout, poor choice of tip, oxidation etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

For lead solder the iron should be at 330 to 350C.  Don’t use a finer tip than you need for the job, make sure the tip itself is properly tinned, and try to create the largest area of contact you can so that the copper pad heats enough to melt the solder directly in to it.  Try to complete the joint before all the flux has burned away (1 to 2 seconds).  If you’re not happy with the initial attempt, add a bit more fresh solder so you have some extra flux.  Also make sure the surface of the copper is clean, use isopropyl alcohol or fine sandpaper if the surface isn’t bright.

Comment: You should emphasize that the majority of the solder goes into the joint, not the iron tip.

Comment: important thing to emphasize, because I misread at first: only use sandpaper if the surface of the *pad* (which, incidentally, should be tin or gold, very rarely will it be unplated copper) isn't bright. *Never* use sandpaper on a soldering iron tip, that's very bad for them.

Comment: Do not use sandpaper on a PCB either! It will very likely damage the solder mask, silk screen, everything. Forget about sandpaper.

Comment: @Lundin - fair comment, if your PCB is so encrusted that scraping it clean is the best option then you’re in trouble already

Comment: @Lundin Good point--the best choice might be a wire brush if you need mechanical abrasion, or just a really aggressive flux (followed by flux remover) to chemically clean it.

Comment: @Hearth Yeah I've occasionally used such brushes. But it will only do so much - flux is the key indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Often I see students apply solder to the soldering iron tip, then try to paint the solder onto the joint. I suspect this is what you are encountering. Don't do this.
Two important points:

1. Oxide and contamination free surfaces. This will create a "wettable" surface that the solder will form an intermetalic  bond with.
   This applies to the component pin, the pad, and the soldering iron tip. Remove any contamination with 99% isopropyl alcohol. Don't use the 70% stuff. It is 30% water. Use flux to remove oxides. Use solder wire that contains flux. Although not always necessary, add flux with a syringe directly to the joint before soldering.
   The soldering iron tip must be bright and shiny for good heat transfer. Apply a little solder to the tip then wipe it off with a brass sponge. This is called "tinning" the tip. Very quickly the tip will start to darken from oxide forming. Re-tin the tip.
2. Enough heat within the joint to melt the solder.
   No matter how wettable the surface is, if the pad is not hot enough, the solder will not melt. Same with the component pin.
   The sequence is to apply a clean, tinned soldering iron to the pad and the pin together. Apply the solder wire to both the pad and the pin without touching the iron. When the joint is hot enough it will melt the solder.

The liquid solder should flow across the pad toward the soldering iron, and up the pin. When cooled the outline of the pin should be visible and concave fillets should appear between the pin and the pad.

The whole process should take no more than 1 to 2 seconds. But don't get in a hurry. The joint must heat up before the solder can melt.

Practice on a board without components. Just apply solder to the pads. Just enough to coat the pad without build up. Watch for how long it takes for the pad to be hot enough. Bigger pads take longer. Conical tips have a very small contact point so heat does not transfer efficiently. Bevel or chisel tips ar better. Pressing harder does not improve heat transfer. Two flat surfaces in contact do. Align the flat of the iron directly with the pad.

Sometimes solder is applied to a tip, then touched to a joint  to make a thermal bridge. Once the bridge is created. Re-tin the iron and solder the joint as usual.

Sometimes components may slide around. Be certain to clamp them some how until the joint has cooled.

I tend to use a hotter iron than most. I find that I take less time to solder the joint. It takes time for the heat to travel into the component so the less time soldering the better.

Answer (score 0):

Use As big as you can fit, even if it's bigger than the pad. Forget the 2/3 rule you see floating around. If you can fit a tip twice as big as the pad in there, do it. I don't go below 2.4mm for most things.

The larger the tip relative to the pad, the less the temperature drop when heat is sucked out when the pad is first touched. That means you do not need to set the temperature as high to compensate. That reduces likelihood of burning because as you hold the tip to the pad and time is allowed for the iron to pump energy into the tip, the tip heat back up to the temperature you set it to. So you want as large a tip as possible so you can set the temperature to be as close to the melting point as possible.

Stay away from conical unless you know for a fact you need it. Chisel is standard, but I find bevel is best. Specifically, a bevel tip with a flat (not spooned or hollowed out face) where only the face is tinned and the sides are untinned. These produce a protruding bead of solder at the tip to produce a viscous liquid metal bead that wraps around everything to make good contact.

Also add your own flux.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is you don't "match" but instead just use a "knife tip" for everything.

When I started soldering I used the classic fine tips.  The issue is poor heat conduction due to lack of metal, leading to long heating cycles.

When I started electronic work professionally I was introduced to the "knide tip" and now use nothing else, even for the finest work.

[image]

(Image from Weller.)

The point (applied sidewise for larger pads) allows you to solder the finest parts (I've done down to 0.35mm pitch), with the bulk ensuring heat gets where it is needed.  Similarly there is enough metal to allow chunky connectors to be soldered with the same tip.

And the best "trick", is that a side sweep of a tinned edge can solder multiple SMT chip pins at once, with surface tension avoiding bridging.

I now always guide others in this direction when they seek help with soldering.

Comment: The biggest problem with these tips isn't fine pitch (covering everything with solder then use lots of flux is a viable method) but when soldering 0603 or smaller - then you simply have to use a smaller tip or you won't even reach the pad.

Comment: @Lundin I must say I've never had that issue, soldering tens of thousands of 0402 parts without problem. I also don't "cover everything with solder", for multilead parts, just a minimum of no clean liquid flux and a side swipe with a well wetted edge. Equally, pin by pin works fine. However you do need to adapt how you apply the tip.

Comment: @Lundin Btw it was talking to a professional assembly house that led me to try this tip for prototyping work, where they indicated it was the only thing their staff used.

Comment: I think it's a bit of personal preference, large chisel/knife tips are clunky when you have lots of 0402 etc sitting closely to each other and its easier to accidentally bump into some other component. When doing tiny stuff like that I have a small, bent tip and a larger chisel tip and swap between them as needed.

Comment: Absolutely agree it is a preference thing. I have from time to tip used conical, but always come back to knife.

Comment: @Lundin That's why I use a flat-faced bevel tip without tinned sides. It makes a protruding solder bead and behaves like a liquid metal tip that is simultaneously massive, but can squeeze into small places. It's pretty cool to shove it onto a part and see it burst out of all the little nooks and crannies, and then withdraw with the tip when you pull it away. Like a T-1000.